# I read a big matrix 300000 x 5000 and I like remove some column with Spark in java

Tags: java, matrix, apache-spark

I try and work with some Spark example, but I not find a way to remove a row after transpose it.

```
CoordinateMatrix cm = new CoordinateMatrix(matrixA.rdd());

BlockMatrix     mat = cm.toBlockMatrix().transpose();
IndexedRowMatrix id = mat.toIndexedRowMatrix();
RowMatrix        rm = id.toRowMatrix();

Vector[] collectPartitions = (Vector[])rm.rows().collect();
```